# Remove words in a list of descriptions

Tags: lists

I'm writing a paper and I use a list to describe some notation in an equation:

*blah blah is described by the equation

x=f(**x**,**u**,**d**),

where **x** is the state vector, **u** (is) the input vector, and **d** (are) the disturbances.*

Do I need the "is" and "are" which I put in parentheses? My gut feeling is that I can skip them, but I have a hard time convincing myself.

Edit: I made a small notation edit and added the word "vector" in two places. If this isn't consistent with what you want to write, you can roll the edit back to your original.

Comment: It is usual in technical writing not to omit any words in order to keep the meaning as clear as possible.

Comment: 'd' has to be a single independent variable. Should this be '...d1, d2 ... are the disturbances'? // x=f(x,u,d) seems to confuse an independent and the dependent variable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Think of **x,u,d** as vectors. They each represent a subset of the state vector. In an aircraft, **x** are related to vehicle geometry and velocity, **u** describe control surface variables and throttle, and **d** could represent a disturbance of interest, such as a downdraft. The subdivisions aren't fixed. The same acceleration might be a velocity disturbance in one analysis, but an acceleration held in **x** in another. This is pretty normal linear analysis notation. The disturbances **d** are usually differentials to values carried in **x**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry for the above, I only just noticed the duplication of "x". Yes, some other variable should be substituted.

Answer (score -1):

when writing the paper with some equation and parameters, we have many ways to describe the parameter in your equation. For example, x=f(x,u,d), where x represents the state, let u and d be the input and the disturbances, respectively.